# asyncio.iscoroutinefunction returns False for asynchronous generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio

The following asynchronous generator code is taked straight out of PEP525:

```
async def gen():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    v = yield 42
    print(v)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

However when I call (with python3.6):

```
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(gen), asyncio.iscoroutine(gen))
```

I get:

```
False, False
```

Why does asynchronous generator fails to identify as a coroutine function?

Is there another way to identify it as a coroutine function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`inspect.isasyncgenfunction()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isasyncgenfunction) (and [`inspect.isasyncgen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isasyncgen) for the result of calling `gen()`):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.isasyncgenfunction(gen), inspect.isasyncgen(gen()))
True True
```

There is no type hierarchy relationship between async functions and async generator functions.

Also, the only reason the `asyncio.iscoroutine*()` functions exist *at all* is to support the [legacy generator-based `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#generator-based-coroutines), which can't be used to create async generators. If you don't need to support older codebases that might still use those (so predating Python 3.5) I'd just stick with the `inspect.is*()` functions.